# Intersection in a Sheaf of Rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf of rings on a topological space $X$, with open subsets $U,V$, with $U\cap V\ne\emptyset$.

If $\mathcal{F}(U)=A$ and $\mathcal{F}(V)=B$, what can be said about $\mathcal{F}(U\cap V)$? Is it isomorphic to $A\cap B$?

Comment: A and B are in general not comparable. They're just rings - to talk about $A\cap B$, you need to have some object containing $A$ and $B$ in some already-known way, and there is no guarantee that this exists.

Comment: In general, as KReiser comments, the intersection makes no sense. But even up to isomorphism this is not even close to true: consider the sheaf of locally constant functions on the plane with values in Z, and let U and V be two open connected sets whose intersection has two connected components.

Comment: Since $U \cap V$ is empty, $\mathcal F(U \cap V)=0$.